# NTFS Drive visible only from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, ssd

I have a 1TB Teamgroup GX2 SSD, I partitioned it into a ~150GB btrfs partition for linux and a 850GB partition for Windows. Then Windows stopped seeing the larger partition, although at the same time it sees the linux partition (btrfs). Windows sees the swap partition as an old partition, and asks to format it. Chkdsk was running before Windows started, but it didn't fix anything. I am using Manjaro Linux+Windows 10 22H2, I partitioned the partitions via Minitool Partition Wizard.

[image]

Comment: Is the NTFS partition *before* or *after* the btrfs partition? My SWAG is that if NTFS does not come first, Windows' old file system drivers "give up" after seeing btrfs.

Comment: can we see screenshot of disk management?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Sure. https://imgur.com/a/ynGT0N5 Linux can even mount this partition, and interact with it. diskmgmt.msc Shows that the drive is RAW, but I know it's actually NTFS.

Comment: Your picture does not match the partition structure described: 1TB = 150 GB + 850 GB. The partition layout on Disk 3 looks like a desaster, by the way.

Comment: If your picture does not match your case description it tells me that you did not do your documentation job carefully. My support experience tells me to stay away from such cases because they have a low success quote. And - what a surprise - there is neither continuation nor solution for you. Think about it! It is your problem, not mine.

Comment: @user389103, please add additional information to your question.  For example, I have pasted teh image their.  Comments get deleted.

Comment: user389103, if you want your problem to be solved it is in your interest to provide detailed and accurate information. That is your duty or "your problem". Complaining when being told that the information delivered is wrong, is outright weird on your side - as if you are not interested in a solution. I would have expected a "thanks for the hint, I have updated the picture".

Comment: @r2d3 All right. I had a Teamgroup GX2 SSD Drive which had a capacity of 953.866GB (1024205818691 Bytes) with a sector count of 2000409264 which was connected to the motherboard using a red SATA III cable. I had 4 partitions: 850.91GB (913657655459 Bytes), a 91GB partition.225 GB with a 1996 BTRFS file system (97925254348 Bytes), an 8GB swap partition (858999934592 Bytes) for the Manjaro operating system with Linux kernel 6.1.22. I apologise if anyone didn't like my partitioning of a 465GB 760MB (50010599991946.24 Bytes) Toshiba HDWD105 hard drive with serial number "Y4IZ16YBK".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem is solved

In the screenshot of Minitool Partition Wizard you could see 900MB of unused space. I simply added them to the 850GB partition, and it was solved. Another interesting thing: In Linux the partition was 850.91MB, but in Minitool it was 850.0GB.

[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYipF.png)

Also, for some reason the grub bootloader was erased. (and/or its entry in ESP), but it's not so critical because I didn't store anything important on the btrfs partition,

https://imgur.com/a/Yjs3Ezc

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to make the genius user389103 even greater again, I strongly recommend always **completely** shutting down your Windows 10. Accessing your windows partition(s) from within linux could devastate your windows partition(s) as it could be still in use by your dormant Windows which is not completely shut down.